# How to trigger function if hold right and left button together with LUA logitech gaming software

Tags: lua, logitech-gaming-software

i have code that if i click scroll button, the script will be activate.

but i want to change to if i hold right and left mouse button the script will be activate, and when right and left button release the script will be deactive

```
local Macro_Activation_Key = 3
local function OutputLogs(s)
   OutputLogMessage(s.."\n")
   OutputDebugMessage(s.."\n")
end 
local Recoil_Activator
function OnEvent(event, arg)
    if (event == "PROFILE_ACTIVATED") then
        EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true)
    elseif event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == Macro_Activation_Key then
        Recoil_Activator = not Recoil_Activator 
        OutputLogs(Recoil_Activator and "ON_Macro" or "OFF_Macro")
    elseif event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 1 and Recoil_Activator then 
        MoveMouseRelative(2, -2)
        repeat
        MoveMouseRelative(-4, 4)
        Sleep(3)
        MoveMouseRelative(4, -4)
        Sleep(3)
        until not IsMouseButtonPressed(1)
        end
    end
```

Comment: How you want to activate the script: press-and-hold LMB then press RMB?  Or press-and-hold RMB then press LMB?

Comment: press and hold RMB then press LMB

Answer (score 0):

Just add the `and IsMouseButtonPressed(3)` to the condition:

```
local function OutputLogs(s)
   OutputLogMessage(s.."\n")
   OutputDebugMessage(s.."\n")
end 

function OnEvent(event, arg)
    if event == "PROFILE_ACTIVATED" then
        EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true)
    elseif event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 1 and IsMouseButtonPressed(3) then 
        MoveMouseRelative(2, -2)
        repeat
            MoveMouseRelative(-4, 4)
            Sleep(3)
            MoveMouseRelative(4, -4)
            Sleep(3)
        until not IsMouseButtonPressed(1)
    end
end
```

Comment: i mean remove the scroll click for the activation and change to i hold RMB and LMB the script will run, i think must change the `Macro_Activation_Key`. if the RMB and LMB release the script will stop 

i already try with chat gpt or etc but dint show any good answer